# (^ap*e$) doesn't match 'apple'. why?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using regular expression in my application and I want to test it for different combinations. How to I specify starts with 'a' and ends with 'e'?

Comment: Use [`^a[\s\S]*?e$`](https://regex101.com/r/uA7hK6/1)

Comment: @Tushar why `[\s\S]` rather than `.`?

Comment: Why is everyone suggesting to match *any* characters? I think what is necessary is the `\w*`: `^ap*\w*e$` to only allow alphanumerics.

Comment: @stribizhev Why not? All they say in the question is `starts with 'a' and ends with 'e'`

Comment: @123: *does not match 'apple'* - definitely not *any* character.

Comment: @stribizhev I would assume it was an example of something they thought it should match, why so abrasive?

Answer (score 4):

`*` matches 0 or more of the previous character.  So your pattern specifies that there will be 0 or more `p`s.

It matches `ae`, `ape`, and `appppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppe`, but not apple.

The typical construct for "match anything" is `.*` (match any character zero or more times) and your pattern would be:

```
^a.*e$
```

Answer (score 3):

Your regular expression works if you add `.` before the star `*`:

```
(^ap.*e$)
```

However, for your requirements there is no need for the `p`, so this will do

```
(^a.*e$)
```

You can explain this regular expression as follows (see this [link](https://regex101.com/))

1. `^` assert position at start of the string
2. `a` matches the character a literally (case sensitive)
3. `.*` matches any character (except newline). The quantifier `*` matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed
4. `e` matches the character e literally (case sensitive)
5. `$` assert position at end of the string

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
(^ap.*e$)
```

You can try testing you REGEX on this website.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Answer (score 0):

> How to I specify starts with `'a'` and ends with `'e'`?

If you're looking for a whole word at its boundaries, like this:

```
\ba\w+e
```

You may want to use the `\b` anchor to match the [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) an the `g` modifier to perform a global match.

```
var result = "apple orange apple banana carrot apple".match(/(\ba\w+e)+/g);
alert(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one `^a(.*)e$` . pattern for starting with 'a' ends in 'e'

Comment: Useless parentheses.

Comment: parentheses are for grouping. gives more clarity that's it. not a sin if you use it

Comment: I know but they can be missleading for a rookie.